# Why does this regex capture produce 2 matches?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, php-5.3

I do not know why there are 2 matches found aside from the input using this regex, when I expected only 1 match.

```
preg_match(/_(\d(-\d){0,3})\./,$str,$matches);
```

on this file string format `name_A-B-C-D.ext`.

I would expect to get a single match like this:

```
Example A
[0] => name_A-B-C-D.ext  
[1] => A-B-C-D

Example B
[0] => name_A-B-C.ext  
[1] => A-B-C
```

But this is the result I get:

```
Example A
[0] => name_A-B-C-D.ext  
[1] => A-B-C-D
[2] => -D

Example B
[0] => name_A-B-C.ext  
[1] => A-B-C
[2] => -C
```

I only wish to capture `A` up to `D` if its preceded with a hyphen.
This code is usable and I can simply ignore the 2nd match, but I would like to know why its there. I can only assume it has something to do with my two capture groups. Where is my error ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you get two captures because you have two capturing groups in your regular expression.

To avoid the unwanted capture you could use a non-capturing group `(?:...)`:

```
/_(\d(?:-\d){0,3})\./
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can only assume it has something to do with my two capture groups.

Your assumption is correct

> Where is my error ?

There is no error, everything is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to groups in your RE, so you get 2 matches.  What is surprising?
Each pair of parenthesis is a group.

Comment: It helps to know how to make a group non-captive ;)